# Get angle from north using iOS api

Tags: objective-c, ios, math, geolocation, gps

Here is what i want:

http://postimage.org/image/9pq8m79hx/

I know the coordonates of the O point and of the X point. Is there any posibility to find the V angle (the angle from North orientation) using iOS methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep.

```
#import <math.h>

float a = -1 * atan2(y1 - y0, x1 - x0);
if (a >= 0) {
    a += M_PI / 2;
} else if (a < 0 && a >= -M_PI / 2) {
    a += M_PI / 2;
} else {
    a += 2 * M_PI + M_PI / 2;
}
if (a > 2 * M_PI) a -= 2 * M_PI;
```

Now `a` will contain the angle in radians, in the interval `0...2 PI`.

Doesn't even need any iOS-specific APIs. Remember: iOS still has all the features of libc.

Comment: @VladBogdan It actually took me 45 minutes to figure out how to do it properly. You haven't made my life easier by requiring that the coordinates be rotated by -PI/2... :D

Answer (score 1):

not sure user529758's answer addresses the question, which I read as being about changing East as 0 degrees to North as 0 degrees. Code below works - key line is 4th line which changes 0 degrees from East to North

```
-(CGFloat) bearingFromNorthBetweenStartPoint: (CGPoint)startPoint andEndPoint:(CGPoint) endPoint {

// get origin point of the Vector
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(endPoint.x - startPoint.x, endPoint.y - startPoint.y);

// get bearing in radians
CGFloat bearingInRadians = atan2f(origin.y, origin.x);

// convert to bearing in radians to degrees
CGFloat bearingInDegrees = bearingInRadians * (180.0 / M_PI);

// convert the bearing so that it takes from North as 0 / 360 degrees, rather than from East as 0 degrees
bearingInDegrees = 90 + bearingInDegrees;

// debug comments:
if (bearingInDegrees >= 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Bearing >=0 in Degrees %.1f degrees", bearingInDegrees );
}

else
{
    bearingInDegrees = 360 + bearingInDegrees;
    NSLog(@"Bearing in Degrees %.1f degrees", bearingInDegrees );
}

return bearingInDegrees;

}
```